# How to batch enumerables in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerable

In my quest to understand ruby's `enumerable`, I have something similar to the following

```
FileReader.read(very_big_file)
          .lazy
          .flat_map {|line| get_array_of_similar_words } # array.size is ~10
          .each_slice(100) # wait for 100 items
          .map{|array| process_100_items}
```

As much as each `flat_map` call emits an array of ~10 items, I was expecting the `each_slice` call to batch the items in 100's but that is not the case. I.e wait until there are 100 items before passing them to the final `.map` call.

How do I achieve functionality similar to the [buffer](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#buffer-int-) function in reactive programming?

Comment: "but that is not the case" - what happens instead?

Comment: Also don't use `map` where you mean `each`.

Comment: What is `FileReader`? In Ruby there is `File.read` but doesn't return an enumerator.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev. each_slice will attempt to divide the enumerable of 10 items into batches of 100. It will, therefore, return the enumerable of 10 items unchanged.
Using each/map is immaterial to the issue.

Comment: @Stefan FileReader is a class I have that uses the `rio` gem to read a file.

Comment: `1.upto(3).lazy.flat_map { |i| [i, i] }.each_slice(3).to_a` returns `[[1, 1, 2], [2, 3, 3]]` which seem correct to me. Maybe you have over-simplified your example?

Comment: "It will, therefore, return the enumerable of 10 items unchanged" - this is not what happens for me.

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Beginning with an empty array `arr`, do you wish to read variable numbers of lines of a file in a cycle, where in each cycle lines are read and elements are appended to `arr` until `arr` contains at least 100 objects, at which time the first 100 elements from `arr` are removed and "processed"? If so, you can't simply chain methods; you'll need to read the file line-by-line, with [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach), say, and then do the necessary operations in `foreach`'s block.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: nah, the methods are perfectly chainable like this, provided that `FileReader::read` (whatever it is) does indeed return an enumerator over lines, like `IO::foreach`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see how `lazy` affects the calculations, let's look at an example. First construct a file:

```
str =<<~_
Now is the
time for all
good Ruby coders
to come to
the aid of
their bowling
team
_

fname = 't' 
File.write(fname, str)
  #=> 82
```

and specify the slice size:

```
slice_size = 4
```

Now I will read lines, one-by-one, split the lines into words, remove duplicate words and then append those words to an array. As soon as the array contains at least 4 words I will take the first four and map them into the longest word of the 4. The code to do that follows. To show how the calculations progress I will salt the code with `puts` statements. Note that [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) without a block returns an enumerator.

```
IO.foreach(fname).
   lazy.
   tap { |o| puts "o1 = #{o}" }.
   flat_map { |line|
     puts "line = #{line}"
     puts "line.split.uniq = #{line.split.uniq} "
     line.split.uniq }.
   tap { |o| puts "o2 = #{o}" }.
   each_slice(slice_size).
   tap { |o| puts "o3 = #{o}" }.
   map { |arr|
     puts "arr = #{arr}, arr.max = #{arr.max_by(&:size)}"
     arr.max_by(&:size) }.
   tap { |o| puts "o3 = #{o}" }.
   to_a
  #=> ["time", "good", "coders", "bowling", "team"]
```

The following is displayed:

```
o1 = #<Enumerator::Lazy:0x00005992b1ab6970>
o2 = #<Enumerator::Lazy:0x00005992b1ab6880>
o3 = #<Enumerator::Lazy:0x00005992b1ab6678>
o3 = #<Enumerator::Lazy:0x00005992b1ab6420>
line = Now is the
line.split.uniq = ["Now", "is", "the"] 
line = time for all
line.split.uniq = ["time", "for", "all"] 
arr = ["Now", "is", "the", "time"], arr.max = time
line = good Ruby coders
line.split.uniq = ["good", "Ruby", "coders"] 
arr = ["for", "all", "good", "Ruby"], arr.max = good
line = to come to
line.split.uniq = ["to", "come"] 
line = the aid of
line.split.uniq = ["the", "aid", "of"] 
arr = ["coders", "to", "come", "the"], arr.max = coders
line = their bowling
line.split.uniq = ["their", "bowling"] 
arr = ["aid", "of", "their", "bowling"], arr.max = bowling
line = team
line.split.uniq = ["team"] 
arr = ["team"], arr.max = team
```

If the line `lazy.` is removed the return value is the same but the following is displayed (`.to_a` at the end now being superfluous):

```
o1 = #<Enumerator:0x00005992b1a438f8>
line = Now is the
line.split.uniq = ["Now", "is", "the"] 
line = time for all
line.split.uniq = ["time", "for", "all"] 
line = good Ruby coders
line.split.uniq = ["good", "Ruby", "coders"] 
line = to come to
line.split.uniq = ["to", "come"] 
line = the aid of
line.split.uniq = ["the", "aid", "of"] 
line = their bowling
line.split.uniq = ["their", "bowling"] 
line = team
line.split.uniq = ["team"] 
o2 = ["Now", "is", "the", "time", "for", "all", "good", "Ruby",
      "coders", "to", "come", "the", "aid", "of", "their",
      "bowling", "team"]
o3 = #<Enumerator:0x00005992b1a41a08>
arr = ["Now", "is", "the", "time"], arr.max = time
arr = ["for", "all", "good", "Ruby"], arr.max = good
arr = ["coders", "to", "come", "the"], arr.max = coders
arr = ["aid", "of", "their", "bowling"], arr.max = bowling
arr = ["team"], arr.max = team
o3 = ["time", "good", "coders", "bowling", "team"]
```